# undefined method `call' for LiquidView:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I trying to use Liquid template engine plugin , but I 'm getting the following error while controller tries to render a .liquid template .

"undefined method `call' for LiquidView:Class"

**product_controller.rb**
@product = Product.find(:first)
render :layout=> false, :template=> "product/show.liquid"

**product/show.liquid**
Product name : {{product.name}}
Price : {{product.price}}

I installed it as a plugin according to 
http://wiki.github.com/tobi/liquid/getting-liquid-to-work-in-rails

I using Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Does anyone had the same problem before ?

Comment: Seems there is a problem with using liquid on Rails >= 2.3.4
See http://groups.google.com/group/liquid-templates/browse_thread/thread/518a507aa7bd10ab/9b67e5e969ae8c61?lnk=gst&q=liquidview#9b67e5e969ae8c61

But I still can't make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Instead installing it using 
script/plugin install http://liquid-markup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

I just downloaded the source from github , extracted and placed it on vendors/plugin directory.

Now I'm able to use .liquid view files on my application .

Thanks ...